# Getting any word and last word using sed

Tags: java, bash, sed

I'm working with the bash shell and now need some back up with a search.

I have a one line java configuration output in which I got two information which I need. These outputs are extremely long and confusing, so I wanted to use sed to clear it up.

So, I tried this:

```
sed -n 's/(.[a-z]*[0-9]*[a-z])/*\([^ ]* *\)/\1 \2/'
```

What I need from the file is Xmx which is build up like this: Xmx1024m

I also need the last word of this line.

Example:

```
was.status.socket=58963 -Dosgi.install.area.configuration.area=opt/was/example -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xcompressedrefs -Djavarofiles/nodeagent/properties/server.policy lastword
```

What I need:

```
Xmx1024 lastword
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks!

KevinD

Comment: What is the pattern here? What do you want to extract? The Xth field? The field containing... what? Specify that.

Answer (score 1):

The following removes everything before Xmx and everything after it up to the last word:

```
sed 's/.*\(Xmx[^ ]*\) .* /\1 /'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/.*(Xmx[0-9]+)m.* /\1 /'
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ echo "was.status.socket=58963 -Dosgi.install.area.configuration.area=opt/was/example -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xcompressedrefs -Djavarofiles/nodeagent/properties/server.policy lastword" | sed -r 's/.*(Xmx[0-9]+)m.* /\1 /'
Xmx1024 lastword
```